# How do I send a variable between Capistrano and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have a Rails app deployed with Capistrano and in our Acceptance environment I want to set the page title to include the branch that is currently deployed.

The branch is set on deploy via Capistrano and I'd like to migrate that info from Cap to Rails somehow.

Obviously I can get Cap to write the branch name out to a file and read it back in Rails, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

I've tried a couple experiments with setting default_environment but that hasn't seemed to work I'm assuming because those environment variables are only present in the shells that Capistrano creates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously I can get Cap to write the
>   branch name out to a file and read it
>   back in Rails

That's the best way, IMO

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that doesn't even need Capistrano, though it does need git. Read the branch name by capturing the output from running a git command in a Rails initializer:

```
# config/initializers/set_title.rb
module MyConfig
  TITLE = `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.chomp.split("/").last
end
```

Then just refer to the constant in your template:

```
<title><%= MyConfig::TITLE %></title>
```

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of something similar too, but the problem with that is that I always end up with a branch of "deploy". I'm not sure if this is an artifact of deploying with Capistrano or something to do with using Github's deploy keys.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It must create a new branch when deploying. You might try grabbing the first line of output from `git log --decorate` which looks like it has the branch name and the tag name from the remote repo. Or maybe git has another way to do this.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it might not necessarily be consistent, but worth looking at. Thanks.